# Verifying solutions to equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is an example of an equation in a text book I've looked at which puzzles me slightly:

We have:

$\sqrt{x+2} = x$

$\Downarrow$

$(\sqrt{x+2})^2 = x^2$

$x+2=x^2$

$x^2-x-2=0$

$(x-2)(x+1)=0$

$x=-1$ or $x=2$

We then have to verify that the solutions are correct.  For $x=2$, we get:

Left side = $\sqrt{x+2} = \sqrt{2+2} = 2$

Right side = $x=2$.

We see that the solution is valid.

For $x=-1$, we get:

Left side = $\sqrt{x+2} = \sqrt{-1+2} = 1$

Right side = $x = -1$

The left side is not equal to the right side, so the solution is not valid.

My question is this:  In the latter verification we have, for the left side, $\sqrt{x+2} = \sqrt{-1+2} = \sqrt{1}$.  But why is it only that the positive square root of $1$ is used in the verification?  After all, $\sqrt{1} = \pm 1$, and if we include the negative solution, then the two sides are equal.

If anyone can explain to me why we do not include the negative solution here, then I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: It's a worldwide agreement amont mathematicians: to avoid misunderstandings and confusion, we **always** choose the positive root of a non-negative real number *nless* otherwise specified. With complex numbers things become messier, but again: it is a matter of *choosing* something..

Comment: @Roby5 I think that's precisely the question of the OP: *why*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Properties_and_uses) $\sqrt{a}$ is the **positive** number x such that $x^2=a$. So, if $\sqrt{x+2}=x$, $x$ **must** be $\ge 0$.

In other words: a correct solution of the equation $\sqrt{x+2}=x$ require the solution of the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
x+2=x^2\\
x\ge 0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This explains it very well :).

Answer (score 1):

> After all, $\sqrt{1} = \pm 1,\dots$

This is not correct.  These two are correct:

$$\sqrt1 = 1$$
$$-\sqrt1 = -1$$

When we say things like $\sqrt{x}$, where $x$ is positive, we just mean the positive square root.  It's a convention.  (Yes, we can take the square root of zero, but $\sqrt0 = 0$ is neither positive nor negative, which is why I'm restricting $x > 0$ for the sake of this discussion.)

On a related note, it is true that both $\pm1$ satisfy $x^2 = 1$, which is why when we solve $x^2 = 1$ we have $x = \pm 1$.  But if we want all $x$ such that $x = \sqrt1$, then only $x=1$ works.  (And likewise if we want all $x$ such that $x = -\sqrt1$, then only $x=-1$ works.)

Comment: Well, one could *also* always choose $\;\sqrt1=-1\;,\;\;\sqrt4=-2\;$ , etc.  and agree on that. True, that'd cause *another* kinds of problems in other parts of the now agreed on mathematics, but there's nothing wrong with taking the negative root per se. The restricition $\;x\ge0\;$ is *necessary* in the real numbers, not merely to make things simpler.

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes, but the OP is clearly at a precalculus level and I don't think such concepts are helpful for questions asked at that level.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input!  This is much clearer to me now :).